# Google Geocharts: custom region

Tags: google-maps

I've found nice feature: https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart
But it looks like Google Geochart allows to choose regions from the fixed list: countries, continents, US states.

Is there any service like Google Geocharts which provides similar functionality with custom regions (polygons or at least points)?

Answer (score 0):

VectorWorkz GeoChart lets you define your own regions and then databind and build heat-maps, etc. on top of those regions. Once you have the region paths, you can easily put together the JSON that the VectorWorkz GeoChart can consume.

Know more about this at [VectorWorkz.com](http://vectorworkz.com/).
VectorWorkz [onlineDemo](http://vectorworkz.com/demo/).

Comment: This link is no longer active